# How does Semantic UI achieve the 'following' behaviour the accordion menu on its site?

Tags: accordion, semantic-ui

On the [Semantic UI Website](https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html) if you view with a large enough screen you'll see an accordion menu on the right hand side. This menu is sticky but also highlights the current section on the page closest to the top of the window. Can someone explain how this is done? Is this extra code just for this site or part of Semantic UI?

[image: Screenshot showing the menu on the right]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done using the visibility module: https://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/visibility.html#how-to-use

Here's the JS from the Semantic UI website: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Docs/blob/70965c088d727355b0c7598add151fcdb103a39f/server/files/javascript/docs.js#L183

Here's a condensed version of what they use:

```
// ready event
semantic.ready = function() {

  // selector cache
  var
    $fullHeightContainer = $('.pusher > .full.height'),
    $container           = $('.main.container'),
    $allHeaders          = $('.main.container > h2, .main.container > .tab > h2, .main.container > .tab > .examples h2'),
    $sectionHeaders      = $container.children('h2'),
    $followMenu          = $container.find('.following.menu'),
    $sectionExample      = $container.find('.example'),
    $exampleHeaders      = $sectionExample.children('h4'),
    $footer              = $('.page > .footer'),

    // alias
    handler
  ;

  // event handlers
  handler = {
    createWaypoints: function() {
      $sectionHeaders
        .visibility({
          observeChanges: false,
          once: false,
          offset: 50,
          onTopPassed: handler.activate.section,
          onTopPassedReverse: handler.activate.previous
        })
      ;

      $sectionExample
        .visibility({
          observeChanges: false,
          once: false,
          offset: 50,
          onTopPassed: handler.activate.example,
          onBottomPassedReverse: handler.activate.example
        })
      ;
      $footer
        .visibility({
          observeChanges: false,
          once: false,
          onBottomVisible: function(calculations) {
            var
              $title = $followMenu.find('> .item > .title').last()
            ;
            $followMenu
              .accordion('open', $title)
            ;
          }
        })
      ;
    },

    activate: {
      previous: function() {
        var
          $menuItems  = $followMenu.children('.item'),
          $section    = $menuItems.filter('.active'),
          index       = $menuItems.index($section)
        ;
        if($section.prev().length > 0) {
          $section
            .removeClass('active')
            .prev('.item')
            .addClass('active')
          ;
          $followMenu
            .accordion('open', index - 1)
          ;
        }
      },
      accordion: function() {
        var
          $section       = $(this),
          index          = $sectionHeaders.index($section),
          $followSection = $followMenu.children('.item'),
          $activeSection = $followSection.eq(index)
        ;
      },
      section: function() {
        var
          $section       = $(this),
          index          = $sectionHeaders.index($section),
          $followSection = $followMenu.children('.item'),
          $activeSection = $followSection.eq(index),
          isActive       = $activeSection.hasClass('active')
        ;
        if(!isActive) {
          $followSection.filter('.active')
            .removeClass('active')
          ;
          $activeSection
            .addClass('active')
          ;
          $followMenu
            .accordion('open', index)
          ;
        }
      },
      example: function() {
        var
          $section       = $(this).children('h4').eq(0),
          index          = $exampleHeaders.index($section),
          $followSection = $followMenu.find('.menu > .item'),
          $activeSection = $followSection.eq(index),
          inClosedTab    = ($(this).closest('.tab:not(.active)').length > 0),
          anotherExample = ($(this).filter('.another.example').length > 0),
          isActive       = $activeSection.hasClass('active')
        ;
        if(index !== -1 && !inClosedTab && !anotherExample && !isActive) {
          $followSection.filter('.active')
            .removeClass('active')
          ;
          $activeSection
            .addClass('active')
          ;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Source: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3323

Comment: Wow I've been using Semantic-UI for many years and have never noticed that one section tucked right at the bottom of the menu! :) Thanks heaps for that :D